# SQL Server basics - where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the code I have:

```
use TSQL2012

select 
    emp.empid, emp.firstname, emp.mgrid, 
    manager.firstname as manager_name,
    sum(unique(emp.mgrid)) as Total
from 
    HR.Employees AS emp, HR.Employees as manager
where 
    emp.mgrid = manager.empid
go
```

And the result I am supposed to get is:

```
   empid firstame mgrid manager_name Total
1   2   Don        1    Sara          1
2   3   Judy       2    Don           2
3   4   Yael       3    Judy          2
4   5   Sven       2    Don           2
5   6   Paul       5    Sven
6   7   Russell    5    Sven
7   8   Maria      3    Judy
8   9   Zoya       5    Sven
```

I can't get the last column (Total). Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Tell us what you're trying to find. (I think I know, but I want to make sure you're clear on it.)

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: Sara is  a manager of Don. Don is a manager of Judy. And so on. Total should represent that Sara is a manager of that many people. I am thinking of using where clause and then use inner join

Comment: I get an error. Coz of sum(unique(emp.mgrid)) as Total

Comment: Do you use mysql or sql server?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is by the use of `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select emp.empid, emp.firstname, emp.mgrid, manager.firstname as manager_name, 
       x.cnt as Total
from Employees AS emp
inner join Employees as manager on emp.mgrid = manager.empid
cross apply (
   select count(*)
   from Employees AS e
   where e.mgrid = emp.mgrid) AS x(cnt)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3905/1)

**Edit:**

You can also use a `CTE` in this way:

```
;With C as ( 
   select b.mgrid, count(*) as Total 
   from Employees as b 
   group by mgrid 
) 
select emp.empid, emp.firstname, emp.mgrid, manager.firstname as manager_name, 
       Total 
from Employees AS emp
inner join Employees as manager on emp.mgrid = manager.empid
inner join C on emp.mgrid = C.mgrid
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3905/2)

Comment: With C as (
select b.mgrid,count(*) as Total from HR.Employees as b
group by mgrid
)
select emp.empid, emp.firstname, emp.mgrid, manager.firstname as manager_name, Total
from HR.Employees AS emp, HR.Employees as manager
inner join b.mgrid = emp.mgrid
where emp.mgrid = manager.empid
go

Comment: Thanks. The above code works. But why is that code not working?

Comment: @Norm Because there is no link between the `CTE` and the rest of the query.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was trying to do.